# Windows 2008 says "not a valid Win32 application" launching from network share, but it works when launching locally - why?

Tags: network-shares, windows-server-2008, terminal-server

I have a mysterious problem on a win2008 terminalserver.

Sometimes a specific programm on a network share throws the "not a valid Win32 application" message at me that could only be solved by restarting the server.

Malware and consistency checks did not pin out.

The share is from the servers harddisk and if I start the program directly from disk it will work flawlessly but not from the mapped network share.

Anyone has an idea how to track this down?

Comment: Have you looked Event Viewer on both situations? If yes, is there any additional error log than the message you get prompted when trying to launch the programme?

Comment: Sadly there is nothing in eventviewer corresponding the error message

Answer (score -1):

In our case it was Symantec's Network Threat Protection causing it randomly. Disabled NTP and problem went away.